# Criteria API (fetch/join). Вложенные сущности. Lazy Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, lazyloading, hibernate-criteria, criteriabuilder

Есть 4 сущности:

1. MainFlows:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "MainFlows")
   public class MainFlows implements Serializable {

       private BigInteger id;
       private String planFact;
       private String fileName;
       private Date settlementDate;
       private float summa;
       private String orgName;
       private String inn;
       private String account;
       private String purposePayment;
       private String payment;
       private UnderFacilities underFacilities;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "UnderFacilityId")
       public UnderFacilities getUnderFacilities(){
           return underFacilities;
       }
       public void setUnderFacilities(UnderFacilities underFacilities){
           this.underFacilities = underFacilities;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Facilityes:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "FACILITYES")
   public class Facilityes implements Serializable {
       private BigInteger id;
       private String facility;
       private String city;
       private String address;
       private Users manager;
       private Set<Users> investors;
       private List<UnderFacilities> underFacilities;

       @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
       public Users getManager(){
           return manager;
       }

       public void setManager(Users manager){
           this.manager = manager;
       }

       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinTable(name = "USERS_FACILITYES",
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FACILITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") },
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RENTOR_INVESTORS_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
       public Set<Users> getInvestors(){
           return investors;
       }

       public void setInvestors(Set<Users> investors){
           this.investors = investors;
       }

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "facility")
       public List<UnderFacilities> getUnderFacilities(){
           return underFacilities;
       }

       public void setUnderFacilities(List<UnderFacilities> underFacilities){
           this.underFacilities = underFacilities;
       }
   }
   ```
3. UnderFacilities:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "UnderFacilities")
   public class UnderFacilities implements Serializable {

       private BigInteger id;
       private BigInteger facilityId;
       private String underFacility;
       private Facilityes facility;
       private List<MainFlows> mainFlows;

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "FacilityId")
       public Facilityes getFacility(){
           return facility;
       }

       public void setFacility(Facilityes facility){
           this.facility = facility;
       }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       public BigInteger getId(){
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(BigInteger id){
           this.id = id;
       }

       @Column(name = "FacilityId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
       public BigInteger getFacilityId(){
           return facilityId;
       }

       public void setFacilityId(BigInteger facilityId){
           this.facilityId = facilityId;
       }

       @Column(name = "UnderFacility")
       public String getUnderFacility(){
           return underFacility;
       }

       public void setUnderFacility(String underFacility){
           this.underFacility = underFacility;
       }

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "underFacilities")
       public List<MainFlows> getMainFlows(){
           return mainFlows;
       }

       public void setMainFlows(List<MainFlows> mainFlows){
           this.mainFlows = mainFlows;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Users:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "USERS")
   public class Users implements Serializable{
       private BigInteger id;
       private String login;
       private BigInteger stuffId;
       private String password;
       private String lastName;
       private String first_name;
       private String middle_name;
       private String email;
       private int office_id;
       private String state;
       private Set<Roles> roles;
       private Stuffs userStuff;
       private MailingGroups mailingGroups;
       private Set<Facilityes> facilityes;


       @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name = "stuffId", referencedColumnName = "id")
       public Stuffs getUserStuff(){
           return userStuff;
       }

       public void setUserStuff(Stuffs userStuff){
           this.userStuff = userStuff;
       }

       @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name = "MailingGroupId", referencedColumnName = "id")
       public MailingGroups getMailingGroups(){
           return mailingGroups;
       }

       public void setMailingGroups(MailingGroups mailingGroups){
           this.mailingGroups = mailingGroups;
       }

       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinTable(name = "USERS_FACILITYES",
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RENTOR_INVESTORS_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") },
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FACILITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
       public Set<Facilityes> getFacilityes(){
           return facilityes;
       }

       public void setFacilityes(Set<Facilityes> facilityes){
           this.facilityes = facilityes;
       }

       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
       @JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLES",
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
       )
       public Set<Roles> getRoles() {
           return roles;
       }

       public void setRoles(Set<Roles> roles) {
           this.roles = roles;
       }
   }
   ```

Пытаюсь достать сущность `Users` из `MainFlows`, но что-то не получается, не выгружается `Facilityes` и `Users`, соответственно получаю `lazy exception`:

```
public List<MainFlows> findAllWithCriteriaApi(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<MainFlows> mainFlowsCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(MainFlows.class);
        Root<MainFlows> mainFlowsRoot = mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.from(MainFlows.class);

        CriteriaQuery<UnderFacilities> underFacilitiesCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(UnderFacilities.class);
        Root<UnderFacilities> underFacilitiesRoot = underFacilitiesCriteriaQuery.from(UnderFacilities.class);

        CriteriaQuery<Facilityes> facilityesCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Facilityes.class);
        Root<Facilityes> facilityesRoot = facilityesCriteriaQuery.from(Facilityes.class);

        Fetch<MainFlows, UnderFacilities> mainFlowsUnderFacilitiesJoin = mainFlowsRoot.fetch(MainFlows_.underFacilities, JoinType.LEFT);
        Fetch<UnderFacilities, Facilityes> underFacilitiesFacilityesJoin = underFacilitiesRoot.fetch(UnderFacilities_.facility, JoinType.LEFT);
        Fetch<Facilityes, Users> facilityesUsersJoin = facilityesRoot.fetch(Facilityes_.investors, JoinType.LEFT);

        mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.select(mainFlowsRoot);

        List<MainFlows> mainFlowsList = em.createQuery(mainFlowsCriteriaQuery).getResultList();

        return em.createQuery(mainFlowsCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```

Как указать, что мне надо вытащить связанные сущности?

UPD:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at com.art.model.Facilityes_$$_jvst68f_8.getInvestors(Facilityes_$$_jvst68f_8.java) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.art.controllers.InvestorsFlowsController.lambda$viewiFlows2$0(InvestorsFlowsController.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.art.controllers.InvestorsFlowsController.viewiFlows2(InvestorsFlowsController.java:102) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: Обновил, @SergeyGornostaev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения нашёл 2.
1. Добавить следующие строки:

```
    public List<MainFlows> findAllWithCriteriaApi(){
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

            CriteriaQuery<MainFlows> mainFlowsCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(MainFlows.class);
            Root<MainFlows> mainFlowsRoot = mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.from(MainFlows.class);

            CriteriaQuery<UnderFacilities> underFacilitiesCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(UnderFacilities.class);
            Root<UnderFacilities> underFacilitiesRoot = underFacilitiesCriteriaQuery.from(UnderFacilities.class);

            CriteriaQuery<Facilityes> facilityesCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Facilityes.class);
            Root<Facilityes> facilityesRoot = facilityesCriteriaQuery.from(Facilityes.class);

            Fetch<MainFlows, UnderFacilities> mainFlowsUnderFacilitiesJoin = mainFlowsRoot.fetch(MainFlows_.underFacilities, JoinType.LEFT);
            Fetch<UnderFacilities, Facilityes> underFacilitiesFacilityesJoin = underFacilitiesRoot.fetch(UnderFacilities_.facility, JoinType.LEFT);
            Fetch<Facilityes, Users> facilityesUsersJoin = facilityesRoot.fetch(Facilityes_.investors, JoinType.LEFT);

            mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.select(mainFlowsRoot);

            List<MainFlows> mainFlowsList = em.createQuery(mainFlowsCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
//Добавлено

            mainFlowsList.forEach(mf -> mf.getUnderFacilities().getFacility().getInvestors().size());
//
            return em.createQuery(mainFlowsCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
        }
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это некий "костыль".

2. Переделал метод на следующий:

   public List findAllWithCriteriaApi(){
           CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

   ```
       CriteriaQuery<MainFlows> mainFlowsCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(MainFlows.class);
       Root<MainFlows> mainFlowsRoot = mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.from(MainFlows.class);
       mainFlowsRoot.fetch(MainFlows_.underFacilities, JoinType.LEFT)
       .fetch(UnderFacilities_.facility, JoinType.LEFT)
       .fetch(Facilityes_.investors, JoinType.LEFT);

       mainFlowsCriteriaQuery.select(mainFlowsRoot).distinct(true);

       return em.createQuery(mainFlowsCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
   }
   ```

Тут приходится использовать `distinct` иначе количество записей возрастает многократно. Буду признателен за комментарии к обоим решениям или если это не оптимальное решение и можно как-то изящней сделать, то тоже буду благодарен.